# $(a,b)$ is saddle point if $f_{xy}(a,b)\not= 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, self-learning

Suppose that $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ that $(a,b)\in V$$\ \ \ \ \ f:V\to\Bbb R$ has second order partial total differential on $V$ with $f_x(a,b)=f_y(a,b)=0$

If the second order partial derivatives of f are continuous and exactly two of three numbers $f_{xx}(a,b)$ $f_{xy}(a,b)$ and $f_{yy}(a,b)$ are zero,

Then prove that (a,b) is saddle point if $f_{xy}(a,b)\not= 0$

---

I think that

Since $f_{xy}(a,b)\not=0$ $$f_{xx}(a,b)=f_{yy}(a,b)=0$$

I want to solve this question by using the theorem.

**Thm:** let $A,B,C\in \Bbb R$ and $D=AC-B^2$ and $\varphi $(h,k)=$Ah^{2}+2Bhk+Ck^2$

if

(i) $D>0$ and A, $\varphi(h,k)$ have same sign $\forall (h,k)\not= 0$

(ii) ıf $D<0$ then $\varphi (h,k)$ takes on both positive and negative valuesas (h,k) varies over $\Bbb R^2$

But, after here, I dont have any idea. Show me the solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take alook at eigenvalues of the hessian (let $s=f_{xy}(a,b)$), which has the form $$\begin{pmatrix}0&s\\s&0\end{pmatrix}$$with $s\ne 0$. It has eigenvalues $\pm s$, so they are of different sign, hence this point is a saddle.

Also, you might want to take a look at [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point).

**Edit**

The theorem you want to use is, actually, studying the bilinear form defined by the matrix $$M=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B&C\end{pmatrix}.$$ If you take a vector $x=\begin{pmatrix}h\\k\end{pmatrix}$ and examine$$x^TMx,$$ you obtain your function $\varphi$.

1) $\varphi$   is always positive for $x\ne 0$ $\iff$ all eigenvalues of $M$ are positive.

2) $\varphi$  is always negative for $x\ne 0$ $\iff$ all eigenvalues of $M$ are negative.

3)  $\varphi$ can be both positive and negative $\iff$ one eigenvalue is positive and another is neagtive.

Note that the position of eigenvalues is decribed in terms of $A$, $B$, and $C$.

In your particular case, look at $x_1= \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, $x_2= \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$; $\varphi(x_1) = 2s$, $\varphi(x_2) = -2s$. Clearly, $\varphi$ can be both positive and negative, hence $(a,b)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to solve this question by using the theorem. **Thm:** let $A,B,C\in \Bbb R$ and $D=AC-B^2$ and $\varphi (h,k)=Ah^2+2Bhk+Ck^2$ if (i) $D>0$ and A, \varphi(h,k)$ have same sign $\forall (h,k)\not= 0$ (ii) ıf $D<0$ then $\varphi (h,k)$ takes on both positive and negative valuesas (h,k) varies over $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: I guess, we say the same things, but I dont know how to prove by using this.

Comment: I added the theorem above question part more readable.

Comment: Why we look at these points $x_1=(1,1)$ and $x_2=(1,-1)$ ?

Comment: Is this an assumption only?

Comment: @Bstr we take vectors (not points) $x_1$ and $x_2$ because they eigenvectors of the Hessian; it's the easiest way to find directions in which the function is increasing (decreasing), hence proving the proposition about the saddle point.